# Tablesorter Range Slider Values to Header - Initial Values Not Showing

Tags: filter, uislider, tablesorter

When I use the filter-formatter uiRange function and set valueToHeader to true, no values show initially. If I move one of the sliders then the range of values show. If I set valueToHeader to false, everything displays fine initially and afterwards.

This issue seems to appear sometime after tablesorter version 2.7.8.

Below is a snippet of how my code looks:

```
1 : function($cell, indx)
{
    return $.tablesorter.filterFormatter.uiRange( $cell, indx, {
         values: [0, 300], 
         min: 0, 
         max: 300, 
         delayed: false, 
         valueToHeader: true, 
         exactMatch: true
    });
 },
```

Thanks for any help.
Regards,
lindon

Comment: That appears to be a bug in the script, I'll have it fixed in the next update.

Comment: Thanks Mottie for the quick response. Look forward to the next update!

Comment: Ok, next update is available and this problem was fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick work - very much appreciated!